# Change persistence unit of ejb via ear

Tags: jpa, ejb, ear

I am developing an ejb component which provides a special query language. The component uses a persistence unit and an entity manager to query the the database.

The user should simply include the component into an ear and just call the `RemoteService` I am providing. This works fine if there is only one persistence unit. But the user might have two or more persistence units.

My question is:
Is there a way to specify the persistence unit used in the ejb component without changing the code of the component? I would like to have a declarative solution like a configuration file entry. I could pass the name of the persistence unit to my service but I dislike it.

Comment: according to what will you switch between the persistence contexts ?

Comment: The user of my component should be able to set the name of the persistence unit without changing my component